Заполнение столбца с данными по предыдущему столбцу excel/notepad/emeditor
Есть столбец с цифрами от 1 до 3 (скриншот 1). Нужно, чтобы второй столбец заполнился в соответствии с цифрами из первого столбца. Если 1, то должно быть 1красный, если 2, то 2желтый, если 3, то 3зелёный (скриншот 2).



Функция ПЕРЕКЛЮЧ

=ВЫБОР(A1;"1красный";"2желтый";"3зеленый")


=ЕСЛИ(A1=1;"1красный";ЕСЛИ(A1=2;"2желтый";"3зеленый"))

